# Derivative of Matrix with respect to matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d,W \in \mathbb{R}^{dxd}$

$\frac {\partial{}}{\partial{W_{i,j}}}(Wx+b)$

What I have done so far is

$W_{i,j}.x_j = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i} W_{1,i}.x_i \\
\vdots \\
\vdots   \\
\sum_{i} W_{d,i}.x_i \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Now if I take the derivative of the product mentioned above, Theoretically it should mean that all the entries of $x$ should be in the answer and the answer would be $x_i$?

Comment: Use a Kronecker product to flatten the matrix to a vector, i.e. $\,W\to w.\,$ Then the equation becomes $(x\otimes I)^Tw +b$ whose gradient is $(x\otimes I)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Wx+b$ is the vector:

$$Wx+b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1+\sum_{k} W_{1,k}.x_k \\
\vdots \\
\vdots   \\
b_d+\sum_{k}W_{d,k}.x_k \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

*(better not to use the indices $i,j$ that are used for the derivation variable).*

$W_{i,j}$ only appears on the $i$-th row of the RHS vector and $\frac {\partial{}}{\partial{W_{i,j}}}(Wx+b)$ is the vector with all entries equal to zero except the $i$-th one which is equal to $x_j$.

Comment: what is the exact meaning of $W_{i,j}$ vector here? doesn't it mean the vector in every row of matrix $W$? after all i,j are only indices here? lets suppose $d=2$ then i will have $Wx =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{k} W_{1,k}.x_k \\
\sum_{k} W_{2,k}.x_k \\
\end{pmatrix}$
What is $W_{i,j}$ here? excuse me for stupid question i am bit new in matrix differentiation

Comment: $W_{i,j}$ is one real entry of $W$: the one at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard notation (where $\delta$ is the [Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol), you have that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}} W_{kh} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jh}$$

which means that the result is $1$ if $i=k$ and $j=h$, zero otherwise. Note that all the four indexes $i,j,k,h$ appear in the final result: this is the simplest derivative of a matrix with respect to another matrix (actually what you are asking for is the derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix).

Now just apply the above rule to your case ([repeated indexes are summed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}} (W_{fs}x_s + b_f) = \frac{\partial}{\partial W_{ij}} (W_{fs}x_s) = \delta_{if}\delta_{js} x_s = \delta_{if}  x_j   
$$
Note that the "dummy index" $s$, namely the "summation index", does not appear in the final result (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\E{E_{ij}}
\def\W{W_{ij}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The component-wise self-gradient of a matrix is given by
$$\eqalign{
\grad{W}{\W} &= \E \\
}$$
where $\E$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ element equals one and all other elements equal zero.

Use this to calculate the component-wise gradient
of the given vector-valued function
$$\eqalign{
y = (Wx + b) \qiq
\grad y{\W} = \E\,x \\
}$$